# SignalR Issue : Cannot connect to Hub class

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I am using `SignalR` in `MVC 5` and trying to create the connection with my `Hub` class (MyHub.cs) through `JavaScript` but getting below error message :

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined`

Here is my code from which I am trying to create connection to `SignalR` :

```
var client= $.connection.myHub;
```

I have explored lot on `google` but not getting any relevant solution. Please help me to figure out this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for this, just remove below line from `web.config`

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to refer below menioned code.
My View Has below menioned code

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
$(function ()
{
    var connectionHub = $.connection.commentHub;
    connectionHub.client.addNewComment = function (comment)
    {

        $("#Comment-list").append("<li>" + comment + "</li>");

    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function ()
    {
        $('#valueofcomment').keypress(function (event) {
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if (keycode == '13') {
                var UserName = '@Session["UserName"].ToString()' + '::' + $("#valueofcomment").val();
                connectionHub.server.addComment(UserName);
                $("#valueofcomment").val("");
                return false;
            }
        });

        $("#InserComment").click(function ()
        {

            var UserName = '@Session["UserName"].ToString()' + '::' + $("#valueofcomment").val();
            connectionHub.server.addComment(UserName);
            $("#valueofcomment").val("");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

ignore the inner logic it's my requirement. you have to just look into the method which used in it.

My CommentHub class look like

```
public class CommentHub:Hub
{
    public void AddComment(string Comment)
    {
        var Context = new SignalREntities();
        Comment com = new Comment();
        com.Comment1 = Comment;
        Context.Comments.Add(com);
        Context.SaveChanges();

        Clients.All.AddNewComment(Comment);


    }

}
```

Comment: As per your code line                                                                                       `var connectionHub = $.connection.commentHub;` is giving error.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bb38z2rn7a69xvk/SignalR.zip?dl=0 Download it from menioned URL and run Comment Controller url look like https://localhost:44302/Comment

Comment: Dude your sample is not working as it is giving errors.